# Junit in Jboss fuse : Waiting for dependency

Tags: json, maven, junit, jbossfuse

I have written Junit for a camel route. The route accepts json input. The service is building and installing fine. I have installed JsonPath bundle in karaf, but I am getting the below exception while running my Junit. I have specified the maven dependency as compile.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Exception message:

> Bundle Test is waiting for dependencies [(&(language=jsonpath)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.LanguageResolver))]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the Camel test. If you provide the source, probably we can give you some ideas.

BTW for a good reference for "How to write Camel test about something" you can check the official repo. I'm attaching you a link to the tests of jsonPath component:

https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-jsonpath/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/jsonpath

Comment: The issue is because I have missed the camel JsonPath dependency in pom. just added it and working fine.